Input type number, step interval, not considering value in textbox
I've a textbox, in which when user clicks top arrow, the value in textbox should increment by 10.
For example, if the textbox value is 12, when user press up arrow, it should show 22, again pressing the up arrow, it should show 32 etc. While clicking down arrow, it should substract 10, so the value that displayed should be 22 (32-10).


<input type="number" id="txtIncrementBy10" step="10" min="0" name="txtIncrementBy10" value="0" />



I provided the step as 10, for this functionality. It is incremented +10 each time user presses up arrow. But the issue I have is it not adding to the value in textbox. Like, if the value in textbox is 33, so pressing up arrow, it shows 40, instead of 43.
Is there a way, for it to add +10 to the value in textbox?
JSFiddle
I have set the interval  to 10, but as mentioned before, when pressing up/down arrow, it is just incrementing value as 10, 20, 30... etc. I want it to add +10 to the value in the textbox instead.

You will need custom +/- buttons, and some javascript. Something like this:


document.querySelectorAll('.number-input').forEach(el => {
  const input = el.querySelector('input');
  const step = Number(input.dataset.step) || 1;
  el.querySelector('.number-input-btn-plus')?.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const value = Number(input.value) + step;
    const max = parseFloat(input.getAttribute('max'));
    if (!isNaN(max) && value > max) {
      input.value = max;
    } else {
      input.value = value;
    }
  });
  el.querySelector('.number-input-btn-minus')?.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const value = Number(input.value) - step;
    const min = parseFloat(input.getAttribute('min'));
    if (!isNaN(min) && value < min) {
      input.value = min;
    } else {
      input.value = value;
    }
  });
});
.number-input {
  --button-width: 16px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  .input {
    padding-right: var(--button-width);
    &::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
    &::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
      appearance: none;
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
}

.number-input-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: var(--button-width);
  height: 50%;
  &:before {
    --arrow-width: calc(0.4 * var(--button-width));
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-left: calc(0.5 * var(--arrow-width)) solid transparent;
    border-right: calc(0.5 * var(--arrow-width)) solid transparent;
    left: calc(50% - 0.5 * var(--arrow-width));
    top: calc(50% - 0.5 * var(--arrow-width));
  }
}

.number-input-btn-plus {
  top: 0;
  &:before {
    border-bottom: var(--arrow-width) solid;
  }
}

.number-input-btn-minus {
  bottom: 0;
  &:before {
    border-top: var(--arrow-width) solid;
  }
}
<label class="number-input" aria-label="Input number">
  <input type="number" data-step="10" min="0">
  <button type="button" class="number-input-btn number-input-btn-plus" aria-label="Plus"></button>
  <button type="button" class="number-input-btn number-input-btn-minus" aria-label="Minus"></button>
</label>




A simplified version of your script could look like this:


document.body.addEventListener("click",ev=>{ // delegated event listening for all current and future input groups
 const btn=ev.target, grp=btn.tagName=="BUTTON" && btn.closest("label.numinp");
 if (grp){ // only step into action if the above requirements were fulfilled
  const inp=grp.querySelector("input");
  inp.value=Math.max(Math.min( +inp.value + +btn.textContent, inp.max||Infinity), inp.min||-Infinity)
}})
button {width: 40px}
input  {width: 60px}
<label class="numinp">
  <button type="button">-10</button>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="200" value="43">
  <button type="button">+10</button>
</label>
<br>
<label class="numinp">
  <button type="button">-7</button>
  <input type="number" min="-50" value="107">
  <button type="button">+9</button>
</label>



A delegated event listener takes care of all the action. In this simple version the increment is specified as the button text (feel free to use a data-inc attribute instead).



const inputField = document.getElementById("txtIncrementBy10");

inputField.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  const currentValue = inputField.valueAsNumber || 0;

  if (event.key === "ArrowUp") {
    event.preventDefault();
    inputField.value = currentValue + 10;
  } else if (event.key === "ArrowDown") {
    event.preventDefault();
    inputField.value = currentValue - 10;
  }
});
<input type="number" id="txtIncrementBy10" name="txtIncrementBy10" value="0" />




It's a type="number", instead of parseInt(inputField.value, 10) you can use inputField.valueAsNumber

I think with the "top arrow" @Ans101 means the array in the inputbox itself. Created an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/4d7t6cav/

@RokoC.Buljan Yes you are absolutely right. Updated code with valueAsNumber 

@Bazardshoxer Your code is not correctly implemented.
